# DCDIAG returns different output in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

When I run the command `dcdiag /test:RIDManager` in PowerShell in my Domain Controller, I get the test as passed.
But when I run it from another server in a different domain using Remote Session in PowerShell I get the test as failed.

```
$testSession= New-PSSession -ComputerName <hostname> -Credential Get-Credential

Invoke-Command -Session $testSession -ScriptBlock {dcdiag /test:RIDManager}
```

This command gives passed when I use the hostname of the Primary Domain Controller but failed for the Secondary Domain Controller. This comes as failed only when I run the command from as Computer in another domain.

I get the below error when failed:

> DsBindWithSpnEx() failed with error 5,
>            Access is denied..

Comment: if i understand your description, that sounds remarkably like the classic "double hop" problem. [*grin*] i recommend you read up on that ... the web has oodles and oodles of articles on the idea.

Comment: Can you clarify what is your issue? i.e. is it Access Denied? because in that case it is likely an account/password issue (make sure you are using a domain admin account for the domain you are accessing). Or, is it the dcdiag command that is failing?

Comment: @HAL9256 I create the remote session in a computer in another domain using the domain's administrator credentials of the target AD server. I get this test alone as failed in the remote session. But when I run it in any computer in that domain it gets passed.

Comment: I don't think it is PowerShell remoting that is the issue. Are you running it locally on the failing secondary server? The `dcdiag` command is computer specific i.e. it is meant to highlight issues with specific domain controllers. see: [Active Directory Replication Error 5: Access is denied](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2002013/active-directory-replication-error-5-access-is-denied)

Comment: @HAL9256 When I run it locally in the secondary server it shows as passed. This error occurs only when run from a server in different domain using powershell remote session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is because of the double hop problem. So if you create a remote PS Session using **Creedssp** then the result is as it is in the target server.